# Google won't update page cache

Tags: google-search, google-index, google-cache

I had a virus donatelloflowfirstly on my page. After cleaning the virus, the site looks like it was before (from any device and IP I tested). However, Google page cache for homepage is still the virus site no matter what I do. I tried to request indexing in Google Search Console (GSC) but nothing happens (for weeks now).

In GSC I tried to remove the site from cache, then cached again. The new cached site was the virus site again.

Weird behaviour is also, the cached (wrong) sites seems random websites, working fine, but having virus site as cached page.

How to solve this problem? Could there be a bug in Google caching system?

Comment: What is webcache.googleusercontent.com?

Comment: @Ben it is a virus site of donatelloflowfirstly. Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/PMCQuGJ.png

Comment: When I go to webcache.googleusercontent.com I am redirected to google.com. I don't know why webcache.googleusercontent.com is supposed to affect your site.

Comment: @Ben the important part is what comes after webcache.googleusercontent.com (in my case its webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.recositech.com). This is how Google see my website, but obviously it is not correct site, but a virus site.

Comment: Your actually site shows up on Google search OK. You probably should sign up for Google webmaster tools. You can ask them to download and check individual pages there.

Comment: @Ben I cannot believe it. This was the real solution (reporting a feedback on GSC). Apparently it was a bug on Google.